# Is it possible to get permanently locked in a room?

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

I ran into a room to escape a monster. The room has no other exits and the monster is pounding on the only door and doesn't seem to be able to get in but isn't giving up. I even lost patience and tried to escape through the monster but he is blocking the door from opening. Am I permanently locked in here?

Comment: Are you in Daniel's room, by any chance? I think that monster won't make it through the door until the player tries to hide from it.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back on what @GGMG said in the comments above.  In order for that Monster to go away you have to hide from it in a dark area.  Meaning, turn out all of the lights in the room you are trapped in and do one of the following (depending on what is available):

- Crouch in a dark corner
- Hide in a Cupboard/Wardrobe
- Hide behind boxes/crouching

And if all else fails you may need to reload last save or try and fight your way out, maybe you can blind the monster [Nope...].  I hope this info helps!  I love Frictional Games and the sheer terror.

Resource: [Amnesia Wikia](http://amnesia.wikia.com/wiki/Hiding)